# Spring Boot OneToOne still load the same data around

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have connected Tables with Foreign key. And my **Spring Boot** Entities like this:

**User.java**

```
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
 @JoinColumn(name = "BASE_USER_CONFIG_ID_FK")
 private BaseUserConfig baseUserConfig;
```

**BaseUserConfig.java**

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "baseUserConfig")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
private User user;
```

When I am trying to load data from Database, data are loading still around and around.

[image]

I need to get only one result with one **BaseUserConfig** data.

Thank You for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it with @JsonIgnore:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "baseUserConfig")
@JsonIgnore
private IamUser iamUser;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is that when spring returns your data in json format it will call the getters and setters of these object you return. Since they are entities that are still linked to an active session this will result in fetching the rest of the data.

One way to resolve this is to work with DTO objects instead of returning you entities.

Answer (score 0):

Its a cyclic response problem while deserialization objects.

eg:

```
public class User {

 BaseUserConfig baseUserConfig; 

} 

public class BaseUserConfig{

 User user;

}
```